# Sql query with aggregate and distinct

Tags: sql, max, distinct

Purpose of query: Employees have several positions each listed in DB. However, the query should return only the positions with the most recent effect_date for each position level.

For example:

```
Employee  Position Position_Level Effect_Date Process_Level
_____________________________________________________________

1        ,  POS1   ,   1     ,       01/01/2000   ,ABC

1        ,  POS1   ,   1     ,       01/01/2002  , ABC

1       ,   POS1   ,   1     ,       01/01/2003  , ABC

1     ,     ABCD   ,   1        ,    01/01/2004 ,  ABC

1       ,   POS1   ,   1        ,    01/01/2005  , ABC

1       ,   POS2  ,   2        ,    01/01/2000 , DEF

1      ,    POS2   ,   2       ,     01/01/2002  , DEF

1    ,      IRHT  ,    2       ,     01/01/2003 ,  DEF

1     ,     POS2   ,   2       ,     01/01/2004 ,  DEF
```

Query should return:

```
Employee  Position Position_Level Effect_Date Process_Level

1     ,     POS1  ,    1     ,       01/01/2005  , ABC

1      ,    POS2    ,  2     ,       01/01/2004 ,  DEF
```

Is this possible to achieve in one query? Since I only need records upto Position_Level = 3, I can do 3 separate queries too but I am having trouble getting 1 distinct record for each position level.

I have this query which I used as a starting point but am obviously not getting the results I need.  Any suggestions?

```
select A.*, B.pos_level,B.employee from (select position,max(effect_date)EFFECT_DATE
from paemppos
group by position) A
JOIN paemppos B 
on A.POSITION=B.POSITION
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, the most efficient way to do this is with `not exists` with the appoprirate index:

```
select p.*
from paemppos p
where not exists (select 1
                  from paemppos p2
                  where p2.employee = p.employee and
                        p2.position = p.position and
                        p2.effect_date > p.effect_date
                 );
```

The best index for this is on `paemppos(employee, position, effect_date)`.

This query is saying:  "Get me all rows from `paemppos` where the employee/position on the row has no larger `effect_date` in the data."

Comment: I think you should add a where condition with the employee ids either.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for the responses. I tried what you suggested and it seems to be giving me the output I need. Thanks!

Comment: Actually @GordonLinoff I take that back. I tried this 
select p.*
from paemppos p
where not exists (select 1
from paemppos p2
where p2.employee = p.employee and 
p2.position = p.position and
p2.end_date > p.end_date)
and employee = 1000
I used end_date instead since it was giving me a more accurate measure on the employee's activeness. However I got two records returned for the same employee and same position_level. They have different positions and one's end date is far more recent than the other's. I need to return only the record with the most recent end_date even regardless of position..

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm sorry if I didn't articulate my comment correctly. I need the most recent position for every distinct position level for an employee returned. Therefore the edit you made does not work either as it only returns the most recent position,not accounting for position level.So for example,if I had 2 records for the same employee, which had different positions, but identical position levels, then I would only want the record with the most recent end_date. If I had 2 records for an employee with identical positions and position levels, i would want the same outcome. Is that clearer?

Comment: @user1949354 . . . I do not see how the query could return multiple rows for the same employee/position combination with different dates.  The strings for employee and/or position could have hidden characters (such as spaces at the beginning or end).